# Convergence in $L^2$ on $C([0,1])$ implies convergence in $L^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

If $f_n \to 0$ in $L^2$ on $[0,1]$, show that $f_n\to 0$ in $L^1$ on $[0,1]$, providing that $f_n$ is continuous for each $n$.

I'm feeling really stupid right now, I can't seem to figure this out. So far, I've written:

$$\int_0^1 |f| = \int_0^1(|f|^{1/2})^2 \le ||f^{1/2}||_2 ||f^{1/2}||_2,$$
but that just gets me right back to where I started. What am I missing?

Comment: $f = 1 \cdot f$

Comment: So, $\int_0^1 |f| = \int_0^1 |f|\cdot |1| \le ||f||_2$, fine, thanks. Where are we using the bounded $[0,1]$ and continuous function conditions? @DanielFischer

Comment: The continuity is not needed.  The boundedness of $[0,1]$ is needed to make $\|1\|_2$ finite.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for clearing that up...

Comment: You might be interested in [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Embeddings).